# pulseaudio drops my sink

Tags: linux, audio, hdmi, pulse-audio

I have a htpc to play music hooked to a tx-sr608 amp via hdmi and this amp hooked via hdmi too to a projector.

HTPC <-> TX-SR608 <-> TV

The sound play nicely when projector is on, when I switch it off or if I don't power it all all, after a random time, usually between 7 and 10 minutes, pulseaudio complains about having ELD info empty (see below) and switches sink, and no audio is heard anymore.

```
Aug 12 11:44:14 bhtpc pulseaudio[1403]: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: ELD info empty (for device=3)
Aug 12 11:44:14 bhtpc pulseaudio[1403]: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Jack 'HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack' is now unplugged
Aug 12 11:44:14 bhtpc pulseaudio[1403]: [pulseaudio] device-port.c: Setting port hdmi-output-0 to status no
Aug 12 11:44:14 bhtpc pulseaudio[1403]: [pulseaudio] module-switch-on-port-available.c: Trying to switch away from port hdmi-output-0, f
ound iec958-stereo-output
Aug 12 11:44:14 bhtpc pulseaudio[1403]: [pulseaudio] module-switch-on-port-available.c: Trying to switch to port iec958-stereo-output
Aug 12 11:44:14 bhtpc pulseaudio[1403]: [pulseaudio] module-switch-on-port-available.c: Finding best profile for port iec958-stereo-outp
ut, preferred = iec958-stereo
Aug 12 11:44:14 bhtpc pulseaudio[1403]: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo becomes idl
e, timeout in 5 seconds.
Aug 12 11:44:14 bhtpc pulseaudio[1403]: [pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Starting to move sink input 0 from 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi
-stereo'
```

I tried to switch dpms off after reading that [bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93946)

I tried to disable module-suspend-on-idle and / or module-switch-on-port-available

I'm at a loss finding why it drops the sink while nothing happens. If I power off/ on the amp the sink goes back up.

Before the sink drops,

```
kodi@bhtpc:~$ pactl list sinks
Sink #12
        State: RUNNING
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo
        Description: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
        Driver: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 6
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor
        Latency: 199214 usec, configured 210000 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS
        Properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
                alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "3"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c10000 irq 29"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "1e20"
                device.product.name = "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (ASUS P8Z77-V LX Motherboard)"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "hdmi:0"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC887-VD"
                alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0887,10438445,00100302 HDA:80862806,80860101,00100000"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, available)
        Active Port: hdmi-output-0
        Formats:
                pcm
```

After the drop

```
Sink #14
        State: RUNNING
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo
        Description: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)
        Driver: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 6
        Mute: yes
        Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
                balance 0.00
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.iec958-stereo.monitor
        Latency: 199114 usec, configured 210000 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS
        Properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "ALC887-VD Digital"
                alsa.id = "ALC887-VD Digital"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "1"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7c10000 irq 29"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "1e20"
                device.product.name = "7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (ASUS P8Z77-V LX Motherboard)"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "iec958:0"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
                device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)"
                alsa.mixer_name = "Realtek ALC887-VD"
                alsa.components = "HDA:10ec0887,10438445,00100302 HDA:80862806,80860101,00100000"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Ports:
                iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority: 0)
        Active Port: iec958-stereo-output
        Formats:
                pcm
```

Any idea ?

Comment: sync = keeping 2 devices in time [abbr. synchronisation]. sink = metal bowl in kitchen for washing dishes.

Comment: The problem is that the EDID (video mode information) also contains the ELD (EDID-like data, which contains audio information), and when the projector is off, there's no EDID, which means there's no ELD, which means the audio subsystem doesn't know which format to use. If you can't configure your amp to send a fake EDID with the correct ELD, you'll have to override the missing EDID/ELD locally. You can do this for the EDID for many video drivers, but I'm not sure how to do it just for the ELD. It might require patching code.

Comment: That makes sense, but if it was the case, then why when I simply boot the pc with just the amp on and never ever switch on the projector, I have sound, pulseaudio correctly chooses the hdmi sink, then it drops after a while. In other words, switching the monito on makes the issue disappear, but if I never start it in the first place, thus impying I would not have a EDID, then why it works for a short period of time ?